# removing unicode hidden space which translates to â€Œ on latin encoding

Tags: php, string, unicode, character-encoding

so i have 2 similar string

```
$no_space    = ',بشکه,';

$with_space  = ',بشکه‌,';
```

i've been doing some query in database when i noticed this similar words return different results ... so i've wrote this little code to compare them character by character

```
$no_space    = ',بشکه,';
$with_space = ',بشکه‌,';


echo '<br /> ------------------------------------------ <br />';
$string  = $no_space; 

echo ' total length : '.mb_strlen( $string , "UTF-8" ).'<br />' ;
 for( $i = 0; $i < mb_strlen( $string , "UTF-8" ); $i++ ) {
    $char_b = mb_substr( $string , $i, 1 , "UTF-8");
    echo $i . ' -> '.$char_b.'<br />' ;
}

echo '<br /> ------------------------------------------ <br />';

$string  = $with_space; 
echo ' total length : '.mb_strlen( $string , "UTF-8" ).'<br />' ;
 for( $i = 0; $i < mb_strlen( $string , "UTF-8" ); $i++ ) {
    $char_b = mb_substr( $string , $i, 1 , "UTF-8");
    echo $i . ' -> '.$char_b  .'<br />';
}
```

so here is the result when i run the code with explorer text encoding set on unicode

```
 total length : 6
0 -> ,
1 -> ب
2 -> ش
3 -> ک
4 -> ه
5 -> ,

------------------------------------------
total length : 7
0 -> ,
1 -> ب
2 -> ش
3 -> ک
4 -> ه
5 -> ‌
6 -> ,
```

as you can see there is a space in the fifth charachter of second string 
but when i run the code with explorere on latin encoding i get this result

```
 total length : 6
0 -> ,
1 -> Ø¨
2 -> Ø´
3 -> Ú©
4 -> Ù‡
5 -> ,

------------------------------------------
total length : 7
0 -> ,
1 -> Ø¨
2 -> Ø´
3 -> Ú©
4 -> Ù‡
5 -> â€Œ
6 -> ,
```

the fifth char gives me `â€Œ` which is clearly not a space , i know that becuz if i add a space in the string i get a space on the output

so what is this `â€Œ` and how can i remove it from my string i've already tried

```
$with_space= html_entity_decode($with_space, ENT_QUOTES, "UTF-8");
```

and even something silly like this

```
$with_space= str_replace('â€Œ', '', $with_space);
```

**pleas note i want to remove these characters from any string not only on database**

Comment: They are multibyte characters. Latin is a single byte font set. See http://kunststube.net/encoding/ and/or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/279170/utf-8-all-the-way-through.

Comment: It looks like you've got the unicode 200c "zero width non-joiner".

Comment: `â€Œ` is `U+200C` encoded as UTF-8 but decoded as `Windows-1252`.